# MonoDevelop yields "Error launching web browser" -- how to fix this?

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop

I have dealt with quite a few oddities of MonoDevelop before, but this one is really starting to bug me. I'm using x86-64 Arch Linux and have the latest of all my packages installed (including MonoDevelop). When I go to run an ASP.Net project, I get

> Error launching web browser
>
> GLib.GException: There was an error launching the default action
>   command associated with this location.   at Gnome.Url.Show
>   (System.String url) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MonoDevelop.Platform.GnomePlatform.ShowUrl (System.String url)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /build/src/monodevelop-2.8.5/src/addins/GnomePlatform/GnomePlatform.cs:134
>   at MonoDevelop.Ide.DesktopService.ShowUrl (System.String url)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /build/src/monodevelop-2.8.5/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/DesktopService.cs:84
>   at MonoDevelop.AspNet.Gui.BrowserLauncher.LaunchDefaultBrowser
>   (System.String url) [0x00000] in
>   /build/src/monodevelop-2.8.5/src/addins/AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Gui/BrowserLauncher.cs:42

How do I fix this? I've read that it's a problem with not using Gnome. I've never used Gnome though and this worked at one time(about a year ago it broke)

Answer (score 15):

The solution that works for me is to type the following command in terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command '/usr/bin/firefox %s'
```

(from http://blog.wolfman.com/articles/2006/8/27/getting-f-spot-to-upload-to-flickr-on-kubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

There were many fixes I've seen listed for this. I tried a few of them (gconf and such)... but nothing worked for me. Probably because I use Fluxbox as my window manager instead of Gnome.

The easiest way I could fix this though is to set the BROWSER environment variable. `export BROWSER=firefox` fixed it for me